# CCRenderTexture iPhone 4 Performance (cocos2d v2/box2d)

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have 2xCCRenderTextures on my screen thats rendering my batchnodes. On iPhone 4s/5/5s game works perfectly, but if I add one or two rendertextures on my iphone 4 fps will be 30 and it's without drawing anything (with drawing its 20)! Where is a problem? iPhone 4 just slow for this or maybe I can change anything? Maybe some optimization? Any help.

My RenderTexture code:

```
 renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram = [[CCGLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderByteArray:ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert
                                                                fragmentShaderByteArray:ccPositionTextureColorAlphaTest_frag];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram addAttribute:kCCAttributeNamePosition index:kCCVertexAttrib_Position];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram addAttribute:kCCAttributeNameColor index:kCCVertexAttrib_Color];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram addAttribute:kCCAttributeNameTexCoord index:kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram link];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram updateUniforms];

alphaValueLocation = 4; //4
renderTexture.sprite.position = ccp(0, 0);
renderTexture.sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);

[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram setUniformLocation:alphaValueLocation withF1:0.8f];
[renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram use];
 [self addChild:renderTexture z:2];
```

Comment: Comparatively the iPhone 4 is the slowest OpenGL ES 2.0 device. It's only 33% faster (in MHz for both CPU and GPU) than the 3GS yet it has a Retina display and thus has to render 4 times as many pixels than the 3GS. It's not unusual to see iPhone 4 performance suffer greatly.

Comment: and nothing I can do about it?

Comment: If the issue is due to the iPhone 4's performance, no. You can of course try to reduce what you do specifically for the iPhone 4, so it may not look as good but still run at 60 fps. But two fullscreen sized render textures plus drawing the screen is *a lot* for that hardware. Perhaps you can render to half the size, then draw the render texture with 2x scale - this may or may not speed things up.

Comment: It's sad to hear that. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: also, fyi ... since iOS 7, i notice that i get lots of memory pressure warnings on iPhone4.